# phpMyAdmin Removing an index

Tags: database, indexing, phpmyadmin, unique

I have a column in one of my tables which has been assigned an index. It is preventing me from having two of the same ID number.

I am assuming the reason it is not letting me have two entries of the same ID is because it has been set to be Unique.

I am wondering how do I remove this rule so that I can insert the same ID number several times.

Cheers

Comment: It may also be because that column was set as a key or primary key.  Look at the table structure and the tools on that page.

Comment: Cheers DGH. I'm pretty sure the guy who made the DB did make it primary.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

below the list of your "columns" in the table structure you have a small table called "Indexes". Every row is an index. Find there your unique index and drop it using "drop" symbol (red X). If you have it on more than one column then drop it and recreate without the column you don't want unique

Comment: In my current version pf PhpMyAdmin, the Indexes panel is collapsed by default. You first need to click on the `+ Indexes` link. (I am unable to determine which version this is...)

Comment: How to Drop a unique index, without DROPPING the Field?

Comment: Yes, it's collapsed by default that's why people can't find it at first sight.

Answer (score 74):

Follow this steps:-

1. Click **Structure** tab of table.
2. Click **Index**(below the table).
3. Click **Drop** for remove index(s).

[image]

Comment: This is an old post. On the new version i can only drop the whole Field. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 13):

In the tab structure below the table the indexes are listed. In some versions of PHPMyAdmin the index are listed only if you click on "+Indexes" which is easy to overlook.

Answer (score 0):

ALTER TABLE `dbName`.`table` DROP INDEX `indexName`